# How to navigate to Related Tab using URL hack?

Tags: custom-object, custom-button, related-list, urlhacking

I am trying to create a list type button which will be added to a related list. Say I have a object name classroom and a object name student who has a lookup field for classroom. Now I wanted to auto populate students new record creation form fields with some similar fields of the classroom. I was able to do that but the problem is when I click the button the modal opens and in the background it shows the details tab instead of related tab. How do I redirect myself to the related tab if I cancel the modal? I tried to use navigationLocation=RELATED_LIST, but it did not work. My url looks something like this

```
/lightning/o/student__c/new?&defaultFieldValues=ref_ContractName__c={!Contract__c.Id},LocAddress__c={!Contract__c.LocAddressId__c}
    &nooverride=1
    &useRecordTypeCheck=1
    &navigationLocation=RELATED_LIST
    &backgroundContext=/lightning/r/Contract__c/{!Contract__c.Id}/view
```

Comment: can you add some screenshots as well to make question clear?

Comment: You can create a custom lightning component if your requirement of opening a modal is not mandatory.

Comment: @maniaccoder It is mandatory and it must look like the default one